# Shorten repetitive Python code

Tags: python, repeat

I'm currently working on a class practice assessment, and I'd like to know if it's possible to shorten my code using loops of some kind?

```
BASIC=500
accident_price = 0
total_price=0
total_price+=BASIC
age=float(input("what is your age?"))
accidents=int(input("How many accidents have you had?"))
for i in range(1):
  if age < 25:
    total_price=total_price+100
    print("Peole under 25 pay extra 100$")
  if accidents == 1:
    total_price+=50
    break
  elif accidents == 2:
    total_price+=125
    break
  elif accidents==3:
    total_price+=225
    break
  elif accidents == 4:
    total_price+=375
    break
  elif accidents == 5:
    total_price+=500
    break
  elif accidents == 0:
    print("No extra charge!")
    break
if accidents > 5:
  print("No insurance!")
  total_price=0
if accidents < 6:
  print("Your total comes to: ${}".format(total_price))
```

Comment: create a dictionary for `accidents`. Also why `for i in range(1)`?

Comment: note that your for loop is completely redundant

Comment: It's already been said by @e4c5, but that's quite a big misunderstanding: `for i in range(1)` means "do that once". This doesn't need any loop.

Answer (score 6):

You can create a dictionary for accidents, something like

```
accident_bonus = {1: 50, 2: 125, 3: 225, 4: 375, 5: 500}
```

Your code can do without the elif series and become like:

```
if accidents in accident_bonus:
    total_price += accident_bonus[accidents]
elif accidents > 5:
    print("No insurance!")
else:
    print("No extra charge!")
```

Also, Ev. Kounis is right. Why `for i in range(1)`? That's not a loop...

Comment: I added the code into a loop because i kept getting errors with the elifs, combined with the two if's. I understand it wasnt at all necessary, it just made it  a bit easier for me to 'understand' what i was doing. :)

Thank you very much for your reply :)

Answer (score 1):

That's probably how I would shorten the code. Shortening it too much comes at a cost of readability and maintainability.

```
BASIC=500
total_price=BASIC
accident_prices = [0, 50, 125, 225, 375, 500]

age=int(input("what is your age?"))
accidents=int(input("How many accidents have you had?"))

if age < 25:
    total_price+=100
    print("Peole under 25 pay extra 100$")

if accidents > 5:
    print("No insurance!")
    total_price=0
else:
    total_price += accident_prices[accidents]

if accidents < 6:
    print("Your total comes to: ${}".format(total_price))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
prices = {
    0: 0,
    1: 50,
    2: 125,
    3: 225,
    4: 375,
    5: 500,
}

age = float(input("what is your age?"))
accidents = int(input("How many accidents have you had?"))
total_price = 500

if age < 25:
    total_price = total_price + 100
    print("Peole under 25 pay extra 100$")

print("No extra charge!"
      if accidents == 0 else
      "No insurance!"
      if accidents > 5 else
      "Your total comes to: ${}".format(total_price + prices[accidents])
      )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
BASIC=500
total_price=0
total_price+=BASIC

age=float(input("what is your age?"))
accidents=int(input("How many accidents have you had?"))

prices_list=[0,50,125,225,375,500]

try:
    total_price+=prices_list[accidents]
    if age < 25:
        total_price = total_price + 100
        print("Peole under 25 pay extra 100$")
except:
    total_price = 0
    print("No insurance!")

if accidents == 0:
    print("No extra charge!")

print("Your total comes to: ${}".format(total_price))
```