# Is there a way to shorten the damage calculation for my Pokemon game? I am constantly repeating lines of code

Tags: python, oop

As you can see, when I am calculating the damage dealt I repeat the typing of the Pokemon. Just wondering if there is a simpler way of writing this code. I was wondering if you could use a table of some sort but am not sure how that can be implemented.
I have provided the majority of my class just in case.

```
class Pokemon:
    def __init__(self, name, types, max_health, health, attack, defense):
        self.name = name
        self.types = types
        self.max_health = max_health
        self.health = health
        self.attack = attack
        self.defense = defense

    #Calculates the damage output depending on their attack and defense attributes
    def move(self, opponent):
        raw_dmg = 0
        choice = int(input("Choose your move: "))
        if choice == 1:
            raw_dmg = int((self.attack / opponent.defense) * 25)
        elif choice == 2:
            if accuracy(70):
                raw_dmg = int((self.attack / opponent.defense) * 40)
            else:
                raw_dmg = 0
        elif choice == 3:
            if accuracy(20):
                raw_dmg = int((self.attack / opponent.defense) * 200)
            else:
                raw_dmg = 0

        #Increases or decereases the damage depending on the type of both pokemon
        if self.types == "Fire":
            if opponent.types == "Water":
                raw_dmg = raw_dmg * 0.5
            elif opponent.types == "Grass":
                raw_dmg = raw_dmg * 2
        elif self.types == "Water":
            if opponent.types == "Grass":
                raw_dmg = raw_dmg * 0.5
            elif opponent.types == "Fire":
                raw_dmg = raw_dmg * 2
        elif self.types == "Grass":
            if opponent.types == "Fire":
                raw_dmg = raw_dmg * 0.5
            elif opponent.types == "Water":
                raw_dmg = raw_dmg * 2
        elif self.types == "Light":
            if opponent.types == "Dark":
                raw_dmg = raw_dmg * 2
        elif self.types == "Dark":
            if opponent.types == "Light":
                raw_dmg = raw_dmg * 2

        #The final damage is randomised by multiplying it by a value between 0.8 and 1.2
        final_dmg = round(raw_dmg * (random.randint(80, 120)) / 100)
        print(final_dmg)
        opponent.health -= final_dmg
        if opponent.health <= 0:
            opponent.health = 0
        return final_dmg
```

Comment: Looks like a question for code review and not SO

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Shorten repetitive Python code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44130326/shorten-repetitive-python-code)

Comment: @Matt Not really. OP's only asking for help with one part, not review of the whole thing. And they're missing the context for that matter. [More info](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/355634/4518341)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whenever it's reasonably possible, it's often good to transform code into data:

Before:

```py
        if self.types == "Fire":
            if opponent.types == "Water":
                raw_dmg = raw_dmg * 0.5
            elif opponent.types == "Grass":
                raw_dmg = raw_dmg * 2
        elif self.types == "Water":
            if opponent.types == "Grass":
                raw_dmg = raw_dmg * 0.5
            elif opponent.types == "Fire":
                raw_dmg = raw_dmg * 2
        elif self.types == "Grass":
            if opponent.types == "Fire":
                raw_dmg = raw_dmg * 0.5
            elif opponent.types == "Water":
                raw_dmg = raw_dmg * 2
        elif self.types == "Light":
            if opponent.types == "Dark":
                raw_dmg = raw_dmg * 2
        elif self.types == "Dark":
            if opponent.types == "Light":
                raw_dmg = raw_dmg * 2
```

After:

```
# ahead of time in the global namespace
SUPER_EFFECTIVE = {
    ("Fire", "Grass"),
    ("Water", "Fire"),
    ...
}
NOT_VERY_EFFECTIVE = {
    ("Fire", "Water"),
    ("Water", "Grass"),
    ...
}

...

        # in the move function
        if (self.types, opponent.types) in SUPER_EFFECTIVE:
            raw_dmg *= 2.0
        elif (self.types, opponent.types) in NOT_VERY_EFFECTIVE:
            raw_dmg *= 0.5
```

Answer (score 1):

Following from [Dennis's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70614123/4518341), I would go a step further and make a dictionary where you can just lookup the multiplier according to the type combination. Then with `.get()`, you can use a default of 1. That makes the code inside the class [flat instead of nested](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/).

```
TYPE_MULTIPLIERS = {
    0.5: [
        ("Fire", "Water"),
        ("Water", "Grass"),
        ("Grass", "Fire"),
        ],
    2: [
        ("Fire", "Grass"),
        ("Water", "Fire"),
        ("Grass", "Water"),
        ("Light", "Dark"),
        ("Dark", "Light"),
        ],
    }

_MULTIPLIER_LOOKUP = {
    types: multiplier
    for multiplier, type_combos in TYPE_MULTIPLIERS.items()
    for types in type_combos}

# ... later

    raw_dmg *= _MULTIPLIER_LOOKUP.get((self.types, opponent.types), 1)
```